# Box2D move bodies at same rate regardless of FPS

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

Sorry, I couldn't word my title properly but I will explain my problem with more clarity here.

I am using libgdx.

When I want to move a Texture so that it covers the same distance with all FPS I will do this:

```
//...define Player class with x property up here.

Player player = new Player();
int SPEED = 100
public void render() {
    player.x += SPEED * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
}
```

Now I want to know how to do this to have the same affect on a body in box2d. Here is an example(the render method of a class that extends ApplicationAdapter):

```
public void render() {

    //clear screen, ... do other stuff up here.

    playerBody.applyForce(new Vector2(0.5f / PIXEL_PER_METER, 0.0f), playerBody.getWorldCenter(), true);
    //PIXEL_PER_METER -> applied to scale everything down

    //update all bodies
    world.step(1/60f, 6, 2);
}
```

This applies a force on the playerBody so that it's acceleration increases. How do I make shore, just like with my first example, that how fast the body is travelling stays constant across at 30fps, 10fps, 60fps, etc. I know the timeStep parameter of the world.step is the amount of time to simulate but this value shouldn't vary.

Thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update all bodies with delta (not 1/60 fixed delta)

```
world.step(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(), 6, 2);
```

EDIT:
As @Tenfour04 mentioned, in order to prevent high delta values (causes huge jumps), we mostly set a cap for delta.

```
world.step(Math.min(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(), 0.15f), 6, 2);
```

Comment: Oh :) I thought that the timeStep parameter had to always have the same value and never change?

Comment: Some game developers implement step logic with a fixed delta (say 1/60). So they make sure that every frame will have the same impact on the game. It is good for multiplayer game implementations i suppose

Comment: still, wouldn't this put a huge disadvantage on someone running the game on a slower machine?

Comment: actually on a slower machine, if you use the actual delta there might be some "jumps". For example if delta gets '2' suddenly, moving objects, collision detections etc will be in trouble

Comment: ha i didnt realise that , well thank you for clarifying, its been bugging me for a while.

Comment: Use a safety net to prevent huge jumps of time that cause physics issues. This will cause slow-mo on extremely slow devices, but is better than the alternative: `world.step(Math.min(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(), 0.15f), 6, 2);`

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use a variable timestep - this is the approach I've used:

```
private float time = 0;
private final float timestep = 1 / 60f;

public void updateMethod(float delta) {
    for(time += delta; time >= timestep; time -= timestep)
        world.step(timestep, 6, 2);
}
```

Basically a variable-ish timestep, but uniformly updating.

If you run your game at very low FPS, or if you force it to with the application configuration (e.g. for testing) this will keep updating at roughly the same speed as a normal 60 FPS instance.

Take a look at [Fix your timestep!](http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/)

Comment: i think your code always works like  world.step(1/60f, 6, 2); since you don't change timestep variable

Comment: @cokceken but the point is it is called a variable amount of times per second which allows it to catch up

Comment: then it is basically same as saying world.step(delta,6,2). User might experience big jumps when delta becomes big

Comment: however this does have an advantage over a simple variable timestep as described in the blog post I linked

Comment: I would prefer not seeing big jumps so i answered that way, you are right about physics simulation to work but i think you shouldn't optimize your game for ~2fps. At 2-10 fps player does not enjoy the game anyway so you can just prevent unexpected situations like jumps and just let the game be slow.